# Cryptanalysis of S-box

Tags: cryptanalysis, s-boxes

Because of implementation constrains, I merge some 4-bit S-boxes to find a 8-bit S-box with good properties such as  nonlinearity, resistance against differential and linear cryptanalysis.
Does the analysis of the larger S-box give us the assurance that we have acceptable security, or we have to check the details of the smaller S-box as well?

Comment: The question is unclear and not answerable for lack of detail on the merging, and on the cipher. Is the merge such that the output of the cipher remains identical without and with the merging? If no, why would any aspect of the original 4-bit S-boxes remain relevant after the merge? If the merge does not change the output: is it assumed that the cipher with 4-bit S-box is secure? If yes, why would any of the envisioned tests on the new S-box be of any use? If no, how would one get convinced that the cipher is secure?